# Material-table multiple data search with selectbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

i wonder if material table have selectbox search for multiple data search in one column like this [image: example]

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1155

Comment: first of all thank you for response, this is not what i want, i want to make (example in picture) on individual column search on every head of column